# MariaDB 5.5: Alter table runs for week, progress shows 0

Tags: mariadb, innodb, alter-table, alter

My table hangs on an ALTER command. It has been running for more than a week. I was wondering if the query is running normally, and I should just wait for it to complete, or something went wrong.

The following query is running on a MariaDB 5.5(InnoDB), and the table has about 2.5M rows and the size of the table about 2.5TB.

`ALTER TABLE Part MODIFY parsedText longtext null`

```
MariaDB [performance_schema]> Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST;
+----+------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+----------+
| ID | USER | HOST            | DB                 | COMMAND | TIME   | STATE                | INFO                                             | TIME_MS       | STAGE | MAX_STAGE | PROGRESS |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+----------+
|  5 | root | localhost:49935 | performance_schema | Query   |      0 | Filling schema table | Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST     |         0.000 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |
|  4 | root | localhost:49859 | skms               | Query   |    553 | NULL                 | show engine innodb status                        |    553727.607 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |
|  2 | root | localhost:49639 | NULL               | Killed  |   2073 | NULL                 | show engine innodb status                        |   2073903.815 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |
|  1 | root | localhost:54213 | skms               | Query   | 761454 | rename result table  | ALTER TABLE Part MODIFY parsedText longtext null | 761454784.333 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+--------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

As you can see from the prcesslist table, `state`, `max state`, and `progress` are all showing 0.
`show engine innodb status` hangs too.

1. why `state`, `max state`, and `progress` are all showing 0?
2. Should I wait for the query to complete, or something went wrong?

Any pointers for further investigation, for circumventing the problem, and for solving are appreciated!

P.S.

The disk has enough space.

Was it MEDIUMTEXT before?
yes.

Disk is HDD or SSD?
HDD

Do you have a separate disk partition for tmp?
No.

How much RAM?
64GB

innodb_file_per_table?
No.

Comment: Was it `MEDIUMTEXT` before?  Disk is HDD or SSD?  Do you have a separate disk partition for tmp?  How much RAM?  `innodb_file_per_table`?

Comment: @RickJames I answered your question in the post.

Comment: Hmmm...  Nothing obvious.  It will take at least as much time as it takes to copy 2.5TB on that disk drive.  I think only one copy will be necessary.  5.5 is rather old; you should upgrade.  Newer versions have improvements to ALTER TABLE.  Another question:  You did the ALTER because some values are approaching 16MB?  There are other limits in the MySQL; you cannot get a full 4GB, even with `LONGTEXT`.  Please elaborate on the type of data you have.